# Is there a way to represent electrostatics tensors in tensor (possibly tensor product) way?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, electromagnetism, tensor-decomposition

I'm working with electrostatic interaction tensors, which are defined as follows:

\begin{align}
    T &= \frac{1}{r} \\
    T^\alpha &\equiv \nabla T = -\frac{r^\alpha}{r^3} \\
    T^{\alpha\beta} &\equiv \nabla \otimes \nabla T = \frac{1}{r^3}\left[ \frac{3r^\alpha r^\beta}{r^2} - \delta_{\alpha\beta} \right] \\
    T^{\alpha\beta\gamma} &\equiv \nabla\otimes\nabla\otimes\nabla T = \frac{3}{r^5}(r^\alpha \delta_{\beta\gamma} + r^\beta\delta_{\alpha\gamma} + r^\gamma\delta_{\alpha\beta}) - \frac{15}{r^7}r^\alpha r^\beta r^\gamma \\
    T^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} &= \cdots
\end{align}

where $r = |\vec{r}|$ is a range between two particles, and Greek indices are Cartesian components $\{x,y,z\}$, so $r^\alpha$, for example, is some component of a vector $\vec{r}$ between two particles.

These are written in terms of their components.
However, I wonder if there's any way to represent them as some kind of formula with other tensors.

For example, the second order tensor $T^{\alpha\beta}$ can (if I'm not mistaken) be conveniently written as
$$
    T^{\alpha\beta} = \frac{1}{r^3}\left[ \frac{3r^\alpha r^\beta}{r^2} - \delta_{\alpha\beta} \right] = \frac{1}{r^3} \left[\frac{3 \vec{r}\otimes\vec{r}}{r^2} - \mathbb{I}\right]
$$
where $\mathbb{I}$ is a 2x2 identity matrix.

But when it comes to higher-order tensors, I'm kinda stuck.
The second term in the third-order tensor is, as far as I understand, can be written as just $\frac{15}{r^7}\vec{r}\otimes\vec{r}\otimes\vec{r}$. But what about the first term with many Kronecker deltas?

So far I've came up with something like this monster
$$
    (r^\alpha \delta_{\beta\gamma} + r^\beta\delta_{\alpha\gamma} + r^\gamma\delta_{\alpha\beta}) =
    r^\alpha\{1,1,1\}\otimes\mathbb{I} + r^\beta \mathbb{I}\otimes\{1,1,1\} + r^\gamma (\mathbb{I}\otimes\{1,1,1\})^T
$$
where $()^T$ means transposing last two dimensions.

So, my questions are

1. Any way of representing this tensor as some tensor products sum?
2. Is there a way outside of guessing to come up with such representations?

Comment: Does you want to use planar matrices?

Comment: Do you have $r^{\alpha\beta} = \delta_{\alpha\beta}$ in the derivation of $ T^{\alpha\beta}$?  The term looks like it should be second-order in $r$.

Comment: Introducing a symmetry operator $\mathcal{S}$ defined (for 3-tensors) by
$$
[\mathcal{S}(T)]_{\alpha\beta\gamma} = \frac{1}{6}(T_{\alpha\beta\gamma}+T_{\beta\gamma\alpha}+T_{\gamma\alpha\beta}+T_{\gamma\beta\alpha}+T_{\beta\alpha\gamma}+T_{\alpha\gamma\beta})
$$
we can write
$$r_\alpha \delta_{\beta\gamma} + r_\beta\delta_{\alpha\gamma} + r_\gamma\delta_{\alpha\beta} = 2[\mathcal{S}(I\otimes\mathbf{r})]_{\alpha\beta\gamma}.$$

Comment: I think that I got the constant incorrect in my previous comment and that it should be $3[\mathcal{S}(I\otimes\mathbf{r})]_{\alpha\beta\gamma}.$